# Calling component in input placeholder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, input

I'm currently trying to call a React component in the position of a text placeholder, but It returns [Object object]. Below is the input

```
render(){
const myText = this.movingText();
<input placeholder={myText}/>
 }
```

then this is the function I'm calling with the component typist tag.

```
movingText() {
  return (
   <Typist>
    Hello this is the text
  </Typist>
    )}
```

So I'm really trying to call the component and its contents as a placeholder. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: placeholder is meant to be a string but you are returning a React component. But what is Typist?

Comment: Typlist is a component that animates a typing process, heres the info https://github.com/jstejada/react-typist

Comment: given this is a component that works with input values in a controlled way, how do you think it will animate a placeholder?

Comment: I think ill have to go about it a different way cause like you said it can only be a string as a placeholder

Comment: @LoseYou21 What solution did you end up with?

Answer (score 0):

In your render...

```
render(){
 const myText = this.movingText();
return(
 <input placeholder={myText}/>

  )
}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to include the return in the original post but it still doesnt work, I think I've found a work around though, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use renderToString from react as below

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
const myText = renderToString(this.movingText());

return(
 <input placeholder={myText}/>
)
}
```